# Blender Not using RX580 GPU even after installing drivers

Tags: rendering, system

System Specs:

```
Ryzen 5 2600 CPU
16GB RAM
RX 580 GPU
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

- Verified GPU compatibility with Blender
- Updated GPU drivers
- Installed the latest version of Blender
- Selected the correct rendering device in Blender
- Verified GPU availability
- Reset Blender's user preferences
- Reinstalled Blender

Current Status:

The issue persists despite trying all the suggested troubleshooting steps.

[image: screenshot the drivers are installed and blender not finding my GPU]